# how to format email body for the text send through php script

Tags: php

Hello I have one contact us page, in which i have one textarea for the description, there user will type his/her message. I want that message to be send in mail body as it is with all the formatting in it. I am getting description from php script

```
$header = "Content-type: text/html\n";
$Description = $_REQUEST["txtDescription"];
mail($To, $Subject, $Description, $header);
```

I have defined $To, $Subject, $header. Mail is going perfectly. I want message to be displayed in mail body, as user typed in textarea with formatting (like enter)

Comment: Well, convert the newline characters to HTML `<br />` tags would do? ... `nl2br($Description)`

Comment: how to convert newline characters to HTML <br /> tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)** to convert new line characters to `<br>` tag.

```
$Description = nl2br($_REQUEST["txtDescription"]);
```

Additionally you can also do the following to preserve **multiple spaces** -

```
$Description = str_replace('  ', ' &nbsp;', $Description);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your newline characters `\n` to `<br/>` using [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) and then send your email in *actual* HTML format.

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Or better yet, use SwiftMailer or PHPMailer. They're a lot more better than `mail()` function and I recommend using them for send emails from your PHP script.

Comment: @smAnkurDhanuka: What isn't working? What happens when you try to echo the data after using nl2br on it?

Comment: $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep formatting, just use `plain/text` instead of `text/html`

Or wrap the message inside `pre` tags:

```
mail($To, $Subject, "<pre>{$Description}</pre>", $header)
```

With content type set on `text/html` the client will try to render it like a browser would do. So same rules as in html will be applied : multiple whitespaces and carriage returns will be treated as one. So you need to use tags that imply (by default) to keep formatting, such as `pre` tags.

Comment: can i keep plain/text and text/html both? because i have some html tag attached in that.

Comment: A mail can be multiparted so you can send a plain/text version and a text/html in the same mail, the client will choose only one version to read. One part of a mail must have only one content-type. So if you want to send html tags in a mail and want the text to keep formatting, you need use `<pre>` or, at least, use CSS properties like this: `<span style="white-space: pre">...` (you can use `span` here or any other tag)

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you should replace textarea with CKeditor

Download from here 
http://ckeditor.com/download

Installation and configuring details on this link

[Ck Editor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: Is there some specific reason for not using it??

Answer (score 0):

If you okey with using TCPDF then use TCPDF

Try this example

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_001.phps